Log convexity implies convexity with Artin definition
I'm trying to prove that log convexity implies convexity using Artin's definition of convexity from "The Gamma Function."
According to Artin, a real-valued function $f(x)$ defined on an open interval $a < x < b$ is convex in this interval if, for all triples of distinct numbers in the interval $x_1, x_2, x_3$, the following holds:
$$
\Psi(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \frac{\varphi(x_1,x_3) - \varphi(x_2,x_3)}{x_1 - x_2} \geq 0,
$$
where
$$
\varphi(x_1,x_2) = \frac{f(x_1) - f(x_2)}{x_1 - x_2}.
$$
My attempt was to manipulate the quotient $\Psi$ for $\log(f(x))$, assuming $x_1 < x_2 < x_3$, and I obtained:
$$
(x_2 - x_3)\log(f(x_1)) + (x_3 - x_1)\log(f(x_2)) + (x_1 - x_2)\log(f(x_3)) \leq 0.
$$
Then, performing the same manipulation for $f(x)$, I got:
$$
(x_2 - x_3)f(x_1) + (x_3 - x_1)f(x_2) + (x_1 - x_2)f(x_3).
$$
However, I couldn't prove that this last expression is $\leq 0$.
I think it should be somehow straightforward, but it's not working out for me.

I would first check if Artin's definition is an elegant alternative definition of standard convexity. A chain of inequalities such as (2) in this answer might help. Then you are done.
